# actionscript 3 external swf loads above the close button

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, swfloader

I'm an as3 newbie, i'm loading external swf files by clicking different buttons but using only one function which works fine.

```
//main
mainCloseBtn.visible = false;
movieloaderbg.visible = false;
M1L1Btn1.visible = false;

//Load activities
var Xpos:Number = 0;
var Ypos:Number = 0;
var swf:MovieClip;
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.x = Xpos;
loader.y = Ypos;
addChild(loader);
// Btns Universal function
function btnClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
    removeChild(loader);
    var newSWFRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("activities/" + event.target.name + ".swf");
    loader.load(newSWFRequest);
    loader.x = Xpos;
    loader.y = Ypos;
    addChildAt(loader,3);
    mainCloseBtn.visible = true;
}
// Btn listeners
wrong.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClick);
// Back btn
backBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, backBtnClick);
function backBtnClick(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    gotoAndStop("M1Lessons");
}
// Video Button
videoBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, videoBtnClick);
function videoBtnClick(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    mainCloseBtn.visible = true;
    M1L1Btn1.visible = true;
    M1L1Btn1.gotoAndPlay(2);
}
//Main Close Button
mainCloseBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mainCloseBtnClick);
function mainCloseBtnClick(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    mainCloseBtn.visible = false;
    loader.unload();
    M1L1Btn1.visible = false;
    M1L1Btn1.stop();
}
```

I'm trying to unload the swfs by clicking on the close button, but the problem is when the swf is loaded i can no longer see the close btn, I've tried to use swap depth but isn't working.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

replace

```
addChild(loader);
```

with

```
addChildAt(loader,0);
```

Comment: Now I can only hear the sound of the external swf file, I can't see it.

Comment: so u're using a background? change 0 to 1. or try and see what position works for your case

Comment: but the close button is above it now, I just need to fix the depth I guess I'm trying change the depth of addChildAt(loader,3) but still there are some movieclips that don't want to get underneath the external swf

Comment: i cant tell from here, i'd need to see the order of childs beeing added.

Comment: Thank you so much! I changed it to addChildAt(loader,9); and it worked! Thnx